# How to detect when a Twilio conversation is set closed (including autoclosed)?

Tags: python, twilio, webhooks, twilio-conversations

If I create a Twilio conversation like so...

```py
conversation = client.conversations.conversations.create(
  friendly_name='foo', 
  unique_name='foo',
  timers_closed='PT24H'
)
```

...after 24 hours the conversation state is set to `'closed'`, as expected. However, the webhook associated with conversation state change (`onConversationStateUpdated`) is not getting called (I think?).

[The docs seem to suggest the webhook is not called](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/states-timers#scenario-4-only-closed-timer-configured), but the phrasing is so odd and that behavior seems so odd, that I don't completely believe it. The docs say:

> Currently, you can only control the post-webhook `onConversationStateUpdated` via the REST API.

Am I correct in my reading? Is a webhook not triggered? Why on earth would I *not* want a webhook triggered here? What's the correct way to detect that a conversation state has changed then?

Answer (score 0):

There are three different "levels" of webhooks: `Global-scoped` and `Service-scoped` and `Conversation-scoped`.

Twilio support claims that `onConversationStateUpdated` event should fire for all levels of webhooks. However, I swear *it will not fire* for me on the global webhook.

My solution ended up being creating a webhook for each conversation which I start with twilio. e.g.,

```
    client = get_my_twilio_client(...)
    convo = client.conversations.conversations.create(
        friendly_name='Foo',
        timers_closed=DURATION_24HRS,
    )
    convo.webhooks.create(
        target="webhook",
        configuration_filters=["onConversationStateUpdated"],
        configuration_url=get_my_webhook_url(),
    )
```